# Is there a way to rename your app other than manually in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, rename

When I want to change my project name from ~"TestingRealApp" to "RealApp" I first go into the folder on my PC and rename the folders. Then I do a find and replace of all testingrealapp to realapp (preserving case).

I am sure this is messy and I might be missing some instances and even corrupting my project. Is there a better way?

I am using Android Studio 0.5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is better way , use refactoring feature.

- Right `click`
- Go to `refactor`
- select `rename`

Do **not** rename manually (`find and replace`) , you could break your `project`.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I looked everywhere for rename but there it is. Appreciate the help.